# Copy QML Item to Clipboard as Image thru C++

Tags: c++, qt, charts, export, qml

I've been trying on with QML Charts API and decided to export the ChartView as image to the Clipboard. I found a working solution surfing on the net, in which one grabs the item as image thru Javascript and sends the QVariant data to C++. This is nice and works but I'm wondering if it wouldn't be possible to send just a QQuickItem* or something as light as that and do the grab and whatever at C++, as everybody says to avoid Javascript as much as possible and grabbing an image seems to be a heavy operation.

Here is the working code I'm using now.

chartexporter.h

```
    #ifndef CHARTEXPORTER_H
    #define CHARTEXPORTER_H

    #include 
    #include 

    class QQuickItem;

    class ChartExporter : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit ChartExporter(QObject *parent = 0);
        Q_INVOKABLE void copyToClipboard(QVariant data);
    };

    #endif // CHARTEXPORTER_H
```

chartexporter.cpp

```
    includes....

    ChartExporter::ChartExporter(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
    {

    }

    void ChartExporter::copyToClipboard(QVariant data){
        QImage img = qvariant_cast(data);
        QApplication::clipboard()->setImage(img,QClipboard::Clipboard);
    }
```

main.qml

```
    import QtQuick 2.7
    import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
    import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
    import QtCharts 2.0

    ApplicationWindow {
        visible: true
        width: 640
        height: 480
        title: qsTr("Hello Chart World")

        ColumnLayout{
            spacing: 2
            anchors.fill: parent

            ChartView{
                id: chart
                title: "Testing Charts"
                anchors.fill: parent
                legend.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
                antialiasing: true
                animationOptions: ChartView.AllAnimations

                PieSeries {
                    id: pieSeries
                    PieSlice { label: "Volkswagen"; value: 13.5; exploded: true}
                    PieSlice { label: "Toyota"; value: 10.9 }
                    PieSlice { label: "Ford"; value: 8.6 }
                    PieSlice { label: "Skoda"; value: 8.2 }
                    PieSlice { label: "Volvo"; value: 6.8 }
                }

            }

            Button{
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignBottom
                text: qsTr("Copy to Clipboard")
                onClicked: {
                    var stat = chart.grabToImage(function(result) {
                                            Printer.copyToClipboard(result.image);
                                        });
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

main.cpp

```
    includes ....
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
        ChartExporter printer;

        QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

        engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("Printer", &printer);
        engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

        return app.exec();
    }
```

Do you guys have an idea on how it could be done by simply calling a method to send the desired Item to C++ as proposed below and processing all stuff in there?

```
    Button{
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignBottom
                text: qsTr("Copy to Clipboard")
                onClicked: {
                      Printer.copyToClipboard(chart);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I kind of found a way to do it in C++!

When I do the Printer.copyToClipboard(chart) inside the onClicked handler (Javascript) I'm actually sending a QObject* to the C++ layer. Inside my C++ method I can do a qobject_cast and grab it as image. One must take into account that the grab operation is asyncronous. So, I needed to do the copy to clipboard inside an slot which gets called when the grab is finished.

So, below is the way I got. If anybody has a better approach it would be nice to know.

chartexporter.h

```
    #ifndef CHARTEXPORTER_H
    #define CHARTEXPORTER_H

    #include <QObject>
    #include <QVariant>
    #include <QSharedPointer>

    class QQuickItem;
    class QQuickItemGrabResult;

    class ChartExporter : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    private:
        QSharedPointer p_grabbedImage;

    protected slots:
        void doCopy();

    public:
        explicit ChartExporter(QObject *parent = 0);
        Q_INVOKABLE void copyToClipboard(QObject *item);
    };

    #endif // CHARTEXPORTER_H
```

chartexporter.cpp

```
    #include <QDebug>
    #include <QImage>
    #include <QQuickItem>
    #include <QClipboard>
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QSharedPointer>
    #include <QQuickItemGrabResult>
    #include "chartexporter.h"

    ChartExporter::ChartExporter(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent), p_grabbedImage(nullptr)
    {

    }

    void ChartExporter::copyToClipboard(QObject* item){
        if(item){
            auto itm = qobject_cast(item);
            p_grabbedImage = itm->grabToImage(QSize(itm->width()*2,itm->height()*2));
            connect(p_grabbedImage.data(), &QQuickItemGrabResult::ready, this, &ChartExporter::doCopy);
        }

    }

    void ChartExporter::doCopy(){
        if(p_grabbedImage.data()){
            auto img = p_grabbedImage->image();
            QApplication::clipboard()->setImage(img, QClipboard::Clipboard);
        }
        disconnect(p_grabbedImage.data(),&QQuickItemGrabResult::ready, this, &ChartExporter::doCopy);
    }
```

main.qml

```
    import QtQuick 2.7
    import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
    import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
    import QtCharts 2.0

    ApplicationWindow {
        visible: true
        width: 640
        height: 480
        title: qsTr("Hello Chart World")

        ColumnLayout{
            spacing: 2
            anchors.fill: parent

            ChartView{
                id: chart
                title: "Testing Charts"
                anchors.fill: parent
                legend.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
                antialiasing: true
                animationOptions: ChartView.AllAnimations

                PieSeries {
                    id: pieSeries
                    PieSlice { label: "Volkswagen"; value: 13.5; exploded: true}
                    PieSlice { label: "Toyota"; value: 10.9 }
                    PieSlice { label: "Ford"; value: 8.6 }
                    PieSlice { label: "Skoda"; value: 8.2 }
                    PieSlice { label: "Volvo"; value: 6.8 }
                }

            }

            Button{
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignBottom
                text: qsTr("Copy to Clipboard")
                onClicked: {
                    Printer.copyToClipboard(chart);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

main.cpp

```
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QQmlContext>
    #include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
    #include "chartexporter.h"

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
        ChartExporter printer;

        QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

        engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("Printer", &printer);
        engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

        return app.exec();
    }
```

Comment: It looks very nice. I didn't try yet.
I just wonder why you used `itm->width()*2` for grab size ? Maybe because your test device has a high pixel density ?
I'll test with [devicePixelRatio](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#devicePixelRatio-prop) factor instead